Enumerate Rest API result returned as nested PSCustomObjects
By rest API call using Invoke-RestMethod I get a result value.
These are members of this variable:
       TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
    
    Name        MemberType   Definition
    ----        ----------   ----------
    Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
    GetType     Method       type GetType()
    ToString    Method       string ToString()
    ha          NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject ha=@{id=ha; name=ha; alias=(ha1); mac=80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx; ip=0.0.0.0; mask=0; link=True; speed=1000,0; duplex=1; tx_packets=151567878; ...
    modem       NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject modem=@{id=modem; name=modem; alias=; mac=00:00:00:00:00:00; ip=0.0.0.0; mask=0; link=False; speed=0,0; duplex=0; tx_packets=0; rx_pac...
    port1       NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject port1=@{id=port1; name=port1; alias=(wan1); mac=80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx; ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; mask=28; link=True; speed=1000,0; duplex=1; tx_pa...
    port2       NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject port2=@{id=port2; name=port2; alias=(wan2); mac=80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx; ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; mask=28; link=True; speed=1000,0; duplex=1; tx_pa...

How do I enumerate and format it using "oneliner" to get this output:
id    name  alias  mac               ip              mask link  speed  dupex ...
--    ----  -----  ---               --              ---- ----  -----  -----
ha    ha    (ha1)  80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx 0.0.0.0         0    True  1000,0 1
modem modem alias  00:00:00:00:00:00 0.0.0.0         0    False 0,0    0
port1 port1 (wan1) 80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 28   True  1000,0 1
port2 port2 (wan2) 80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 28   True  1000,0 1


Why do you need a "oneliner"? Even directly in the shell you can just use multiple lines. Oneliners only overcomplicate things without adding a single advantage. To format the output as a table you can use the Format-Table cmdlet (which has ft as an alias) where you can also specify which columns you want

You can try to get in oneliner:
$result | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | ForEach-Object { $result."$($_.Name)" } | Select-Object id, name, alias, mac, ip, mask, link, speed, duplex | Format-Table -AutoSize

Sample (mimicking the API response: result_sim.ps1):
$result = [pscustomobject]@{
    ha    = [pscustomobject]@{id='ha'; name='ha'; alias='(ha1)'; mac='80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx'; ip='0.0.0.0'; mask=0; link=$true; speed='1000,0'; duplex=1};
    modem = [pscustomobject]@{id='modem'; name='modem'; alias=''; mac='00:00:00:00:00:00'; ip='0.0.0.0'; mask=0; link=$false; speed='0,0'; duplex=0};
    port1 = [pscustomobject]@{id='port1'; name='port1'; alias='(wan1)'; mac='80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx'; ip='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'; mask=28; link=$true; speed='1000,0'; duplex=1};
    port2 = [pscustomobject]@{id='port2'; name='port2'; alias='(wan2)'; mac='80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx'; ip='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'; mask=28; link=$true; speed='1000,0'; duplex=1};
}
$result | Get-Member 

$result | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | ForEach-Object { $result."$($_.Name)" } | Select-Object id, name, alias, mac, ip, mask, link, speed, duplex | Format-Table -AutoSize

Output:
PS C:\> .\result_sim.ps1


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
ha          NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject ha=@{id=ha; name=ha; alias=(ha1); mac=80:80:2c:...
modem       NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject modem=@{id=modem; name=modem; alias=; mac=00:00...
port1       NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject port1=@{id=port1; name=port1; alias=(wan1); mac...
port2       NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject port2=@{id=port2; name=port2; alias=(wan2); mac...



id    name  alias  mac               ip              mask  link speed  duplex
--    ----  -----  ---               --              ----  ---- -----  ------
ha    ha    (ha1)  80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx 0.0.0.0            0  True 1000,0      1
modem modem        00:00:00:00:00:00 0.0.0.0            0 False 0,0         0
port1 port1 (wan1) 80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   28  True 1000,0      1
port2 port2 (wan2) 80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   28  True 1000,0      1


I do not understand nested objects/hashtables/PSCustomObjects.
Why I am not able to use foreach with .Name and .Value or .Keys to iterate through this hashtable of hashtables?

I have found the answer:
$result.PSObject.Properties.Value | Format-Table -AutoSize

This is the real-life example, Rest API call to FortiGate firewall:
PS C:\Users\Administrator> ((Invoke-FGTRestMethod -method "get" -uri "api/v2/monitor/system/interface").results).PSObject.Properties.Value | Where-Object { $_.link -eq $true } | Format-Table -Property * -AutoSize

id     name   alias     mac               ip              mask link   speed duplex  tx_packets  rx_packets       tx_bytes       rx_bytes tx_errors rx_errors
--     ----   -----     ---               --              ---- ----   ----- ------  ----------  ----------       --------       -------- --------- ---------
ha     ha     (ha1)     80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx 0.0.0.0            0 True  1000,0      1   151953694    81804680   116928881045    30040423380         0         0
port1  port1  (wan1)    80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   28 True  1000,0      1  4086617369  5786771409  1380322273902  6931269974674         0         0
port2  port2  (wan2)    80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   28 True  1000,0      1    84875237    74035578     7194117864     8430803244         0         0
port9  port9  (hasync1) 80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx 0.0.0.0            0 True  1000,0      1  2533226689   102875469   403641506354    21197598810         0         0
port10 port10 (hasync2) 80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx 0.0.0.0            0 True  1000,0      1  2534531472   102815829   403904500544    21205581100         0         0
port16 port16 (ha2)     80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx 0.0.0.0            0 True  1000,0      1    45488363    45488698    23199065105    23062771267         0         0
x1     x1     (lag1x1)  80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx 0.0.0.0            0 True 10000,0      1 20697600233 18869420127 17831218782164 14999955561979         0         0
x2     x2     (lag1x2)  80:80:2c:xx:xx:xx 0.0.0.0            0 True 10000,0      1 19831046658 18625813596 16447442621499 13276128503027         0         0

PS C:\Users\Administrator>

By the way, it is nice to see how the traffic is evenly load balanced between LAG members.

I understand that when you call $result in PS you receive the output as a list.
$result | Format-Table

will convert it to the output you request
Ref:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.4


I wouldn't ask if it was that easy. Because the Rest API call result are PSCustomObjects nested in another PSCustomObject, just formating cannot be used. You need to get variables from inner PSCustomObjects.
